# Keeping Application running

Tags: vb.net, console-application, system.timers.timer

I am trying to keep an application open until a file appears.  I am using a timer to check the FTP server every 60 seconds (file could take 13 to 15 minutes before it shows up).

The while loop works...but it takes up 50% of my CPU.  Trying to figure out another way.  I was looking into adding a Windows.Form and using the Application.Run(), but was wondering if the Application.Exit() would close my application.

```
    Public Shared Function CheckStatus(ByVal TaskID As String) As Boolean
        _TaskID = TaskID

        'Start Timer to Check Query Status Every 10 Seconds
        CheckStatusTimer.Interval = 10000
        CheckStatusTimer.Enabled = True
        CheckStatusTimer.Start()

        'Wait for Check Query Status To Complete
        While _Status = False

        End While

        CheckStatusTimer.Stop()
        CheckStatusTimer.Enabled = False

        Return _Status
    End Function
```

Could placing the CheckStatusTimer.Stop() into completion logic section of my CheckStatusTimer_Tick() Subroutine.  How can I prevent the calling function from returning until the timer is stopped?

Thanks
jlimited

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking call is called `Thread.Sleep()`:

```
    While _Status = False
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    End While
```

This means the thread will check every 500 milliseconds (0.5s) if the Status is different.

Answer (score 0):

This what you need to work with a task in background:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Another thing, these lines are wrong:

```
CheckStatusTimer.Stop()
CheckStatusTimer.Enabled = False
```

You're repeating, start() method and enabled=true property perform the same thing, also stop() method and enabled=false

Here's a tutorial of how to download a file in background mode

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229675(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)